# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 - Problems when change contextPath

Tags: spring-roo

**clinic example**

I have change the contextPath in `application.properties`:

```
server.contextPath=/tierklinik
```

When I start the application now the url is `http://localhost:8080/tierklinik`, but when I will add something new (create) then I get error side and the URL is not correct.

Url after save:

```
http://localhost:8080/tierklinik/tierklinik/pets/
```

I have a normal spring boot application and the contextPath change work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in the Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 applications.

Check the `<form>` element of your `create.html` and `edit.html` files. You could see that the `action` attribute of the form is defined like this:

```
data-th-action="@{${collectionLink.to('create').with('item', item.id)}}"
```

Removing the `@{` and the final `}` you should obtain the following value for the `action` attribute:

```
data-th-action="${collectionLink.to('create').with('item', item.id)}"
```

The problem is that the `@` includes the contextPath in the URL, but the `collectionLink` and the `itemLink` includes it too.

If you want to apply this change to all your HTML views, you could update the `.ftl` files instead the `.html` files installing the templates with the command `web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF` and updating them. After this update, opening the Spring Roo shell again, all your `.html` files will be regenerated removing the `@` from the action attribute.

Hope it helps,

Regards,

Comment: Remember to validate the answer if it solves your problem ;) Regards